# How to skip a lot of values when define const variable with iota?

Tags: go, enums, constants, iota

Say I have next c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
    enum RC {
        APPLE=0,
        ORANGE,
        PEAR,
        BANANA=99,
        GRAPE
    };

    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", APPLE, ORANGE, PEAR, BANANA, GRAPE);
}
```

The output is:

> 0, 1, 2, 99, 100

**If in go, how can I use a `more golang way` to handle that?**

In fact, if I just want to skip some value. e.g. print `0, 1, 2, 5, 6`, then I can use next to skip some value, but here I need to skip 96 values...

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    const (
        APPLE = iota
        ORANGE
        PEAR
        _
        _
        BANANA
        GRAPE
    )
    fmt.Println(APPLE, ORANGE, PEAR, BANANA, GRAPE)
}
```

And, also I can use next, but I still have many const variable after `GRAPE`...

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    const (
        APPLE = iota
        ORANGE
        PEAR
        BANANA = 99
        GRAPE  = 100
    )
    fmt.Println(APPLE, ORANGE, PEAR, BANANA, GRAPE)
}
```

So, is there any `more golang way` for me to handle such kind of situation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Single group, manual offset

You may shift the [`iota`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota) with a constant, and leave subsequent initialization expressions empty:

```
const (
    APPLE = iota
    ORANGE
    PEAR
    BANANA = iota + 96 // 96 is manually calculated to get 99
    GRAPE
)
fmt.Println(APPLE, ORANGE, PEAR, BANANA, GRAPE)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5T49-crUMXZ)):

```
0 1 2 99 100
```

Although if you insert elements before `BANANA`, values of `BANANA` and subsequent constants will change.

### Breaking the constant group

If you want to avoid that, break the constant group, and start a new (the value of `iota` is reset to `0` whenever the reserved word `const` appears in the source):

```
const (
    APPLE = iota
    ORANGE
    PEAR
)
const (
    BANANA = iota + 99 // iota is reset to 0
    GRAPE
)
fmt.Println(APPLE, ORANGE, PEAR, BANANA, GRAPE)
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-wyw6LoavHV).

### Single group, automatic offset

If you don't want to break the constant group, there is still a solution.

Introduce a constant in the place where you want to "break" the numbering, and subtract its value from `iota` in the the subsequent line. This will result in `1`, and so shift this with the amount minus 1 you want to continue from. This way even if you insert elements before `BANANA` (but not between `_BREAK` and `BANANA`), ordinals of `BANANA` and subsequent constants won't change.

```
const (
    APPLE = iota
    ORANGE
    PEAR

    _BREAK

    BANANA = iota - _BREAK + 98 // Continues from 98 + 1 = 99
    GRAPE
)
fmt.Println(APPLE, ORANGE, PEAR, BANANA, GRAPE)
```

Output again is the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dsvHEVBkJk5).

Depending on your taste, `_BREAK` may be initialized with `iota + 1`, so the offset to apply on the next constant will be the value it gets:

```
const (
    APPLE = iota
    ORANGE
    PEAR

    _BREAK = iota + 1

    BANANA = iota - _BREAK + 99 // Continues from 99
    GRAPE
)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8cMDD7CCCP5). Use whichever looks easier to you.

Comment: Great, what I needed.